# jQuery is duplicating POST requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I've made a web page that sends data to a page via jQuery.  The form can be duplicated by clicking "New".  For some reason, the submit function is run multiple times.  If I create three forms, and click "Submit" on the first one, it makes three entries for that.  The form is then deleted.  When I submit the second form, it makes two entries, and so forth.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the following code?

```
function listen() {
$(".addBook").on('click', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".loadingImg").fadeIn();
    });
    var target = $(this).parent();
    var title = $(target).find(".bookTitle").val();
    var author = $(target).find(".bookAuthor").val();
    var genre = $(target).find(".bookGenre").val();
    var barcode = $(target).find(".bookBarcode").val();
    var img = encodeURIComponent($(target).find(".coverSelect").val());
    var data = 'barcode=' + barcode + '&title=' + title + '&author=' + author + '&genre=' + genre + '&img=' + img;
    $.post('addBook', data, function() { alert(title); });
    $(this).parent().parent().slideUp("med", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
}


//new form function
function newBook(barcode) {
var data = 'barcode=' + barcode;
$.post('bookInfo', data, function(data) {
    $('.accordion').append(data);  //php script returns html for form
    $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    $("#closeAccordion").show();
    listen();
});
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: We would need to see html and the "new form" and "delete form" functionality. The given code would work with html that matches it.

Comment: If the entire form is being duplicated, does that mean the button/link that is labeled .addBook is also duplicated? If that's the case, then what is happening is when you click the an .addBook item, it fires for ALL items with class .addBook on the page. (Just a guess which is why I'm not making it an answer. Need to see more info per @KevinB's comment.)

Comment: "when you click the an .addBook item, it fires for ALL items with class .addBook on the page." What? Absolutely not it doesn't. Can you substantiate this claim?

Comment: A note about: `var target = $(this).parent(); var title = $(target).find(".bookTitle").val();`... `target` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it again in the next lines.

Comment: @JasCav That's not true, it would only fire for clicked element. the click only happened on one element.

Comment: I don't see anything in the given code that would make it possible to get duplicate posts without the user double clicking.

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: @KevinB Neither do I, but it does duplicate it.  I've added some code above.

Comment: as-is, your event should only exist on forms that initially appear on the page, not dynamically added forms. Is that what your `listen` method fixes?

Comment: @KevinB The listen() function is called every time a form is created (see code above).  Would that create multiple listeners for the same event, and how would I fix that?

Comment: Yes, you're binding the event over and over, use event delegation instead. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding duplicate events, instead, just use event delegation so that you don't even need to call `listen()`.

```
//function listen() {
$(document).on('click', '.addBook', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".loadingImg").fadeIn();
    });
    var target = $(this).parent();
    var title = $(target).find(".bookTitle").val();
    var author = $(target).find(".bookAuthor").val();
    var genre = $(target).find(".bookGenre").val();
    var barcode = $(target).find(".bookBarcode").val();
    var img = encodeURIComponent($(target).find(".coverSelect").val());
    var data = 'barcode=' + barcode + '&title=' + title + '&author=' + author + '&genre=' + genre + '&img=' + img;
    $.post('addBook', data, function() { alert(title); });
    $(this).parent().parent().slideUp("med", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
//}


//new form function
function newBook(barcode) {
var data = 'barcode=' + barcode;
$.post('bookInfo', data, function(data) {
    $('.accordion').append(data);  //php script returns html for form
    $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    $("#closeAccordion").show();
    //listen();
});
}
```

**Note:**
You should replace `document` with a selector that selects whatever element you are appending forms to, such as `.accordion`.

```
$('.accordion').on('click', '.addBook', function() {....
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you bind the button when a new form is generated.
When you do it you will bind the same event to one button that already have a click event attached.
Then, when you click all events will run.

Use `click` or `on('click', ...` to prevent this behaviour.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHvU5/)

Answer (score 1):

With oldest jquery you can use the "live" and "on('click')" solution, but before it, you also need to "kill" the bindings with die and unbind.

In 1.9+ jquery version the "live(..." syntax replaced with "on(..." syntax.
Keep in mind the Upgrade / Change stuff.

On(.. syntax usage:

```
 $("#myButton").on("click", function(){
    alert("you call me!");
});
```

About old binding methods you can found some doc's [here.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)